# Plot predicted values for interaction in fixed effects model using `plm`

Tags: r, plm

I'm struggling to graph the predicted probabilities generated by a repeated-measures experiment analyzed using the `plm` package.

The experimental data I am analyzing is a repeated-measures experiment. People are asked to make 8 choices between different types of products.  The order in which these products appear (`product`, an 8-level factor variable) is randomized.  At every point in time, a person is either assigned to a discount or no discount (the dichotomous var `discount_i`).

My theory posits that there is an interaction between a continous attitudinal variable (`iipm`, 0-12) and the discount (`discount_i`), but not the product. Thus, my model is as follows:

```
fixed <- plm(chose ~ iipm*discount_i+factor(product), data=df, index=c("time", "id"), model="within", family='binomial')
```

I'm using a basic fixed effects model to account for time as well as dependence between observations, but I'm NOT INTERESTED in the effect of time, per say.  **What I'd like to do is generate 8 product specific interaction plots of the predicted probability of choice, with the continuous variable (`iipm`) on the X-axis and the levels of `discount_i` being the two lines of predicted values**.

Please help!  A bit tricky for my current skill level.

Sample data (which should be balanced, I hope!) below:

```
> dput(sample_data[1:128,])
structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L), .Label = c(" A1FC4ZLFOKK2B9", " A22HZJIW9LEIS0", 
"A002160837SWJFPIAI7L7", "A09265903LS1OKAES4KAC", "A10B7OQ3GMIFD3", 
"A10ELK3KP57KWE", "A11F2KD14NFQ0A", "A11HTX95941MJI", "A12SMSQ6D5227J", 
"A12VWKFS6N0SV6", "A13HSR88OUNIVP ", "A14OFQMJ2Q6BTI", "A14OK6VJZDJ421 ", 
"A14W00II6N5ADC", "A14W0AXTJ3R19V", "A15DIISD5XBWHK", "A15E4I3BZKHNUV", 
"A1640357KEVPIW", "A1650FELH3UL2F", "A16KTSWXO8ZLMO", "A1835XBNR2UB4X", 
"A18ACKRAVMM8D8", "A18TXM6GMU1411", "A19F9CLZ0XWBYR", "A1A25FXEVMBSOA", 
"A1AJG4BGSRPC93", "A1AU8R78QWNKJD", "A1AYTEFEX5B89X", "A1BDBKDS7F7OMW", 
"A1BQEX75BE1AYE", "A1BXEU20OCUGVZ", "A1CAMCK95M88CN", "A1CIIX0CB0GR7H", 
"A1CTJ8UT7SF317", "A1ED68DLJ8YFWM", "A1EWHJ42DLEL37", "A1EWQ6YCM8CO0E", 
"A1F8MOWCCVDIH2", "A1GK40XYRMZHP7", "A1HFYKYYG9MW8G", "A1HI6CVPXJ70L1", 
"A1I2DD7WM94VC2", "A1I6551IZGYWM8", "A1ITBXITLY2952", "A1J4BNCH0HIQ98", 
"A1JMINVUZ2AOZR", "A1JMUSGZ7RN22X", "A1JXS7PBKBEVHT", "A1KEC6S4OBBE2U", 
"A1KJV3S1EK7LUT", "A1LMGLI5F2ZT4W", "A1M72TTFPE00AM", "A1NM7ZPZ3NH412", 
"A1OKNQ2JEXW34Q", "A1OQIXAU1SEJ4P", "A1OV86I0FAFAM1", "A1PA4WGAPB8LUV", 
"A1PLDF2A9RJD3J", "A1Q8L9UA8SAPIQ", "A1QK6O24KDVLJ1", "A1QR6I7UPY8XQJ", 
"A1QTQISKEHWSKZ", "A1R4F6EPXA3VCL", "A1R8A1ZKR80MRA", "A1S5W9N861BFLD", 
"A1SB15LP2XJVVT", "A1SG4CCCMLF8W2", "A1T5YMBH35PDBX ", "A1T78PV59MJ88L", 
"A1TH8X83SGT5ZE", "A1U81IXEMNUMX2", "A1UE8XA52IFAIV", "A1UH396UOK0X9Z", 
"A1WDSSOA9GW1T", "A1WUBD5BHESJVV", "A1XLGIFFGB01EU", "A1XSXTWJ4SDFXD", 
"A1YS3RYTSEXSGH", "A1YSYI926BBOHW", "A1ZERM9X4BHQV2", "A1ZHF9MHTINO5S", 
"A1ZN6M815BQV96", "A200LNG7PDSUGZ", "A209PPOU3RKN8E", "A20ASMCESA51U4", 
"A20IA63WXHF683", "A2177MS5XTPHK4", "A21ULKCLHVAACL", "A21YQXPL0SNNR2", 
"A220JLNQJ2WL33", "A22CF8BF9YQND7", "A22LZ62E0UC4VL", "A22R7DT2XQIKXV", 
"A22XK2FSFIAAFG", "A23AWSZSAGLY8X", "A23HJNY3F7Z9CS", "A23JA6ICO4BPQ5", 
"A243FYB6B3DG2S", "A244Q3FRPL4R3D", "A24LUXW1DB1QI5", "A257UIPAZR9NTN", 
"A25ZADCJI3D5AF", "A269JSFR6BWAW3", "A27CDEZVU8HL0N", "A27IABVBUZ9X8Z", 
"A27MJOV91GA8R3", "A28NJNZ3NRZ85T", "A28PG3NQXF9VAA", "A28QG7I54E4XAD", 
"A2958CGPRRIV04", "A29VL3MZE7YPBZ", "A2APPZDU0VS9LN", "A2AR2PLDAHHB28", 
"A2AU7FRKEQ0OHE", "A2AXGNA291U5BF", "A2BAFU5B5G2AVX", "A2BTJFHP7WQY23", 
"A2CWLWWRIK3IX3", "A2D2XQP00IZFR1", "A2DTTNGUXTEGHQ", "A2EEUQ0YY2XIU", 
"A2EHRNN23UBSJA", "A2EI075XZT9Y2S", "A2EM7RPFW3DU9N", "A2F2ASKIB0U2LM ", 
"A2FLCDTES3YD5I", "A2FZMW0KCCVLXR", "A2G8UI423QZYJJ", "A2GHZI45J9CN9R", 
"A2H18EYM79ZRCW", "A2H8GNSEVUJXYL", "A2HW7UTK78JAKG", "A2I7S2991CE4XO", 
"A2I9PUZT19ZBO8", "A2IRXCL5YW5RAS", "A2J6T9ELNZ97JH", "A2J7PEUIO2WVUN", 
"A2JVZUU107CL6Y", "A2KFOOEQWGN0GK", "A2NVUN3MHY8LMQ ", "A2OFN0A5CPLH57", 
"A2OW2CIT4H7364", "A2PPTAURU5AAQB", "A2QB3M030UWH53", "A2QLSHXNCHBRN4", 
"A2QZV6QX8WXJUN", "A2R10YXGQ9MTJ6", "A2R1CERP22ICFT", "A2R4B6OJPIW0HQ", 
"A2RMOCDLA2JSO5", "A2S96ZZ70YFPSK", "A2SPN23MCH9RKP", "A2TG7EEQ2XG2IK", 
"A2U81N228679L1", "A2UKT57LG0TWD1", "A2UO3QJZNC2VOE", "A2VDLRRPXV3N59", 
"A2VZB11NR1QC0S", "A2WLGVXAVT2XTR", "A2WZDY9R2GHRXD", "A2XM6C78S9L8UG", 
"A2XS49LRNX8PD4", "A2Y0SIZH81B265", "A2Y0ZGI29KQBTB", "A2YGVQGMU5AQYY", 
"A2YTOX7SEDJ1TC", "A2YYQJ3JWA2KGD", "A2Z8F0B2YGRFEY", "A30MS11FPNF1DS", 
"A316ZWBTQ7PGE7", "A31O3Y1D4EVLRP", "A321FJYVTX5WP9", "A321UTTHJSC5PO", 
"A32VLTWRJ1EP5T", "A32ZPYIWFEUCDX", "A33B6YFHZCMDUC", "A33BFK8KFKJ3IA", 
"A341G96EYJLBKF", "A347XXV5JH19PB", "A3485MZKNDDAMK", "A352QIC9QSCQEM", 
"A35OGKV242IJ78", "A3696JXTRKL2FI", "A372KQ73N0RZLJ", "A37533SGF100SL", 
"A37BWMULVPH2XJ", "A37I58C4258IPX", "A37NI374J4UNXD", "A37WXDYYT7RCZ0", 
"A3862RIFFUV141", "A38TCB4NTM5093", "A38USYKE9P7Z9O", "A39PGXN2A70UN5", 
"A39YE1VEL5T2XF", "A3ACR8IG31Q7K6", "A3AP1NCEBBR8S0", "A3APC5DH14Q0E2", 
"A3AWWFCNLAYW90", "A3B6BODCYK2O7L", "A3B6DOMIUDYB3I", "A3BFRHKQ94MZBX", 
"A3BM05OXSUCJII", "A3BUX2X4NAIB3K", "A3CCBRS9NU71R8", "A3CO5374TFUFEK", 
"A3D7JEGMSYKCUJ", "A3DD0FNVTIY7GO", "A3DU2ZHN459R53", "A3E8SXH0BAYG85", 
"A3EU5A0CGLUBRZ", "A3FDSQADGUY42E", "A3FG68U6LZ8EGN", "A3FWFXTCHEX9UM", 
"A3G9MSZVWB7W42", "A3GPR8TTDAX01S", "A3HKOZ90IDUZ8Z", "A3HLCR4YCHJWBI", 
"A3HQYWUW66HG1J", "A3IE6ATDKX6N1H", "A3J22SWYT5NPX6", "A3JZS32RQUWGJM", 
"A3KWA2ORU9M9IF", "A3M5CBY1V1FCX2", "A3MWV912LNFD67", "A3NH3BCC6GHEWR", 
"A3O1L0034OG341", "A3OWP3M7I9AQ44", "A3Q45OPFL3R49", "A3Q4T34SDWIHU9", 
"A3QB0Z9AN62HFH", "A3QM71HR4ZP65N", "A3QSJY1FFN0N6V", "A3QY3I5O0STFGA", 
"A3RTMAO8QC1Z97", "A3T7N659X3PGKV", "A3TBA7X9EF16W6", "A3TFAAGSW70079", 
"A3TXO6RKFIDFUV", "A3UX6ETXQOCG65", "A3VIM82WAK5TIZ", "A3W1LG4JXLNCL", 
"A50BRZM8LHWCD", "A5N8JGDID098C", "A669K8QT6PVVF", "A6IVYRP8FAIS", 
"A7D1FSJZSM3MJ", "A7EUXC5Q4675O", "A7I3G380E29VE", "A8BFVGGZ06DEC", 
"A8BLFGJE6RDQK", "A8FAG8ZFEM7FP", "A9JLQEN9J5WL3", "A9KJJHT79BXS8", 
"AA7ZQGZUR6V5E", "AAVJV2EYBWESX", "AC5LU9TF9CTK9", "ACJJUQ96T22RC", 
"ACNM6EM54CKRT", "ACPHZ1AG8XAQ0", "ACWYF9Z50PCA9", "ACZXP89TIXCUA", 
"ADQKQCMH1ALS6", "AEQWOTF1QN1MK", "AFB9N61OMZXCX", "AFHAH1BIN51GI ", 
"AG4LR5A7TCRH9", "AG7WQ3TB100SO", "AGF9EJ5F4E45D", "AGJ6958FU8A4N", 
"AHMFDP04U8I02", "AI1JF1C8UK1CX", "AIC8ALJV5X9OY", "AJB0OAEIYGY87", 
"AJETFLAXRDTKJ", "AJSTOFYJCC87B", "AM2V91APQ1DYH", "ANUXUJE8QRE0C", 
"AO3XB5I5QNNUI", "AO4ZHD0B9KUNE", "AOF7TQQOL7IT8", "AOKQZBHA40IBW", 
"AOLU7V2SEBS75", "AOT04CJ43L5V1", "AOVB3KCIIJLRJ", "APC3O2O8O9XPO", 
"APGX2WZ59OWDN", "AQ36OBO2GRA00", "AQ7YZUJW31SEL", "AQEVAKQLI09EN", 
"AQLG9XLOAUWUH", "AR95C0P53AFWJ", "ARVSVYBL46LC9", "AS3BSFKKBAN8J", 
"AS8XVJ2TNN58J", "ASH55LLJVVBOZ", "ASXIEBMMWW1NE", "AT0COJ1G23ZB0", 
"AT3HYOVRFTGNH", "ATHS9GUME1XCA", "ATJQG32KDCYMO", "AULC5HR1BBHMA", 
"AUN8AE8UCO3MD", "AUO7XEZDY9496", "AUSCGO1H49UY2", "AV5PNRD316L5R", 
"AVZ76FUE8VET9", "AWPAWDDLEEPTC", "AYG3MF094634L", "AYQWBIUVDPBXK", 
"AYSX5GNO640MZ", "AYZ85PU887QY1", "AZ1RJVNOZFIWV", "AZA8EVH0RZAR9", 
"AZCV8JQ2NEFN8", "AZOAW8JH5HJJK"), class = "factor"), product = c("Soap", 
"Chocolate", "Shampoo", "Batteries", "Tees", "Cleaner", "Jelly", 
"Coffee", "Soap", "Chocolate", "Shampoo", "Batteries", "Tees", 
"Cleaner", "Jelly", "Coffee", "Soap", "Chocolate", "Shampoo", 
"Batteries", "Tees", "Cleaner", "Jelly", "Coffee", "Soap", "Chocolate", 
"Shampoo", "Batteries", "Tees", "Cleaner", "Jelly", "Coffee", 
"Soap", "Chocolate", "Shampoo", "Batteries", "Tees", "Cleaner", 
"Jelly", "Coffee", "Soap", "Chocolate", "Shampoo", "Batteries", 
"Tees", "Cleaner", "Jelly", "Coffee", "Soap", "Chocolate", "Shampoo", 
"Batteries", "Tees", "Cleaner", "Jelly", "Coffee", "Soap", "Chocolate", 
"Shampoo", "Batteries", "Tees", "Cleaner", "Jelly", "Coffee", 
"Soap", "Chocolate", "Shampoo", "Batteries", "Tees", "Cleaner", 
"Jelly", "Coffee", "Soap", "Chocolate", "Shampoo", "Batteries", 
"Tees", "Cleaner", "Jelly", "Coffee", "Soap", "Chocolate", "Shampoo", 
"Batteries", "Tees", "Cleaner", "Jelly", "Coffee", "Soap", "Chocolate", 
"Shampoo", "Batteries", "Tees", "Cleaner", "Jelly", "Coffee", 
"Soap", "Chocolate", "Shampoo", "Batteries", "Tees", "Cleaner", 
"Jelly", "Coffee", "Soap", "Chocolate", "Shampoo", "Batteries", 
"Tees", "Cleaner", "Jelly", "Coffee", "Soap", "Chocolate", "Shampoo", 
"Batteries", "Tees", "Cleaner", "Jelly", "Coffee", "Soap", "Chocolate", 
"Shampoo", "Batteries", "Tees", "Cleaner", "Jelly", "Coffee"), 
    chose = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), discount_i = c(1, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0), iipm = c(9, 4, 9, 
    4, 4, 9, 4, 4, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 10, 8, 10, 10, 6, 8, 4, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 
    0, 1, 8, 4, 8, 8, 4, 8, 3, 8, 7, 6, 7, 0, 6, 7, 4, 0, 9, 
    11, 9, 4, 11, 9, 2, 4, 8, 7, 8, 4, 7, 8, 4, 4, 4, 10, 4, 
    0, 10, 4, 7, 0, 6, 8, 6, 8, 8, 6, 2, 8, 7, 7, 7, 4, 7, 7, 
    5, 4, 1, 8, 1, 5, 8, 1, 5, 5, 11, 9, 11, 10, 9, 11, 7, 10, 
    11, 10, 11, 11, 10, 11, 9, 11, 5, 8, 5, 4, 8, 5, 7, 4), time = c(7, 
    1, 8, 4, 2, 6, 5, 3, 7, 8, 5, 3, 4, 2, 1, 6, 4, 3, 1, 2, 
    6, 8, 7, 5, 1, 4, 7, 6, 8, 3, 5, 2, 3, 6, 1, 5, 4, 8, 7, 
    2, 3, 8, 2, 6, 4, 7, 1, 5, 2, 1, 8, 7, 3, 5, 4, 6, 4, 2, 
    3, 7, 1, 8, 6, 5, 5, 2, 6, 7, 3, 4, 8, 1, 7, 1, 8, 5, 3, 
    6, 4, 2, 1, 5, 3, 4, 7, 2, 6, 8, 6, 3, 4, 2, 1, 5, 8, 7, 
    6, 4, 2, 3, 8, 5, 7, 1, 7, 1, 8, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6, 1, 6, 3, 
    7, 8, 2, 4, 5, 3, 8, 5, 6, 1, 7, 4, 2)), .Names = c("Q97", 
"product", "chose", "discount_i", "iipm", "time"), row.names = c("108.soap", 
"108.choc", "108.shampoo", "108.batt", "108.tee", "108.clean", 
"108.jelly", "108.coffee", "220.soap", "220.choc", "220.shampoo", 
"220.batt", "220.tee", "220.clean", "220.jelly", "220.coffee", 
"241.soap", "241.choc", "241.shampoo", "241.batt", "241.tee", 
"241.clean", "241.jelly", "241.coffee", "152.soap", "152.choc", 
"152.shampoo", "152.batt", "152.tee", "152.clean", "152.jelly", 
"152.coffee", "247.soap", "247.choc", "247.shampoo", "247.batt", 
"247.tee", "247.clean", "247.jelly", "247.coffee", "205.soap", 
"205.choc", "205.shampoo", "205.batt", "205.tee", "205.clean", 
"205.jelly", "205.coffee", "173.soap", "173.choc", "173.shampoo", 
"173.batt", "173.tee", "173.clean", "173.jelly", "173.coffee", 
"132.soap", "132.choc", "132.shampoo", "132.batt", "132.tee", 
"132.clean", "132.jelly", "132.coffee", "78.soap", "78.choc", 
"78.shampoo", "78.batt", "78.tee", "78.clean", "78.jelly", "78.coffee", 
"10.soap", "10.choc", "10.shampoo", "10.batt", "10.tee", "10.clean", 
"10.jelly", "10.coffee", "137.soap", "137.choc", "137.shampoo", 
"137.batt", "137.tee", "137.clean", "137.jelly", "137.coffee", 
"114.soap", "114.choc", "114.shampoo", "114.batt", "114.tee", 
"114.clean", "114.jelly", "114.coffee", "304.soap", "304.choc", 
"304.shampoo", "304.batt", "304.tee", "304.clean", "304.jelly", 
"304.coffee", "149.soap", "149.choc", "149.shampoo", "149.batt", 
"149.tee", "149.clean", "149.jelly", "149.coffee", "21.soap", 
"21.choc", "21.shampoo", "21.batt", "21.tee", "21.clean", "21.jelly", 
"21.coffee", "107.soap", "107.choc", "107.shampoo", "107.batt", 
"107.tee", "107.clean", "107.jelly", "107.coffee"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I think you want an interaction plot, I am not sure what you want product to interact with? It is only a direct effect in the model above.

Comment: Hi there @Seth - I'll clarify my language.  I want to make interaction plots of `iipm`*`discount_i` faceted BY product. Thus, 8 separate graphs of the twoway interaction.

Comment: Some people consider Amazon Worker IDs to be personally-identifiable information

Answer (score 0):

This may be close to what you want.

```
interaction.plot(df$iipm, df$product, predict(fixed), col = 2:9, lty = 1)
```

[image]